# Prove that this function is constant if it has constant argument

Tags: complex-analysis

This question was asked in my complex analysis quiz.

> Let f be holomorohic on U and assume that for each r $\in$ (0, 1) , f($re^{it} )$ has constant argument. Show that f must be constant.

The solutions of quiz are not given and I have no idea on which result I should use. I have done some questions in assignment related to proving a function to be constant but this is very different than them and I have no idea on which result to use.

Can you please help?

Comment: What is $U?\,\,$

Comment: @zhw. Unit disc with centre origin. I hope it's common notation so I didn't wrote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $0<r<1,$ let $C_r$ denote the circle $\{|z|=r\}.$

Assume $f$ is not constant. Then $f'$ does not vanish identically. Hence the zero set of $f'$ is at most countable. Thus $f'$ is nonzero everywhere on some $C_r,$ which we now view as fixed.

Now $\arg f$ is given to be constant on this $C_r.$ This implies $f(C_r)$ is a subset of some open ray from the origin. We can rotate $f$ so that this ray is $(0,\infty).$ I.e., we choose $c\in \mathbb C, |c|=1$ such that $cf(C_r)\subset (0,\infty).$

The function $g(t) = cf(re^{it})$ is then a smooth postive real valued function of period $2\pi.$ Hence $g$ has a maximum at some $t_0,$ giving $g'(t_0)=0.$ But $$g'(t_0) = cf'(re^{it_0})ire^{it_0}\ne 0,$$ since $f'$ is nonzero on $C_r.$ That's a contradiction, proving $f$ is constant as desired.

Comment: what is the contradiction if zeroes of f' are uncountable?

Comment: Suppose $g$ is holomorphic in the open connected set $V.$ There are only two possibilities: i) $g\equiv 0$ ii) the zeros of $g$ are isolated. In case ii) the zero set of $g$ is at most countable.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that $f(z) \ne 0$ for $0 < |z| < 1$ so that the argument of $f(z)$ is well-defined. The idea is to show that $zf'(z)/f(z)$ is purely imaginary and therefore constant, and then derive a contradiction unless $f' \equiv 0$.

For fixed non-zero $z \in U$ and real $t > 0$ is it given that $f(ze^{it})$ and $f(z)$ have the same argument, so that
$$
 \frac{f(ze^{it}) - f(z)}{f(z)}
$$
is a real number. Now we consider the identity
$$
 i \frac{f(ze^{it}) - f(z)}{ze^{it} - z} \cdot \frac{z}{f(z)} \cdot \frac{e^{it}-1}{it} = 
\frac{f(ze^{it}) - f(z)}{f(z)} \cdot \frac 1t \, .
$$
For $t \to 0$ the left-hand side has the limit
$$
 i f'(z)\cdot \frac{z}{f(z)} \cdot 1
$$
and the right-hand side is a real number for all $t > 0$. It follows that
$$
 i\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)} \in \Bbb R
$$
for all non-zero $z \in U$. From the open mapping principle we can now conclude that the left-hand side is constant:
$$
 i\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)}  = k \in \Bbb R
$$
for all non-zero $z$ in $U$. If $k=0$ then $f'$ is identically zero and we are done.

If $k \ne 0$ then necessarily $f(0) = 0$ with some multiplicity $p > 0$ and we get a contradiction from
$$
p = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)} = -ik \, .
$$